# How to box a formula in MathJax?

Tags: latex, mathjax

How do I draw a box around a formula in MathJax?

I've seen \boxed{} recommended for LaTeX in general, but MathJax doesn't support that operation. Is there an alternative that does the trick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\boxed is in the AMSmath extension, so if you put "TeX/AMSmath.js" in the extensions array of your configuration, you will be able to use the \boxed{} macro.  Alternatively, try \fbox{}.

Comment: Thanks! I also tried \fbox -- it gives the long division symbol in the version I was using, but supposedly the new beta doesn't have that problem.

Comment: MathJax v1.1 is now officially released (no longer beta).